# Why with and without * make difference in Bash

Tags: bash

[Updated]

I'm trying to figure out parameter substitution, especially about `${var#Pattern}` and `${var##Pattern}`.

According to [the doc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html):

${var#Pattern} Remove from $var the shortest part of $Pattern that matches the front end of $var.

${var##Pattern} Remove from $var the longest part of $Pattern that matches the front end of $var.

Now when I run the following, I expected that the third and the fourth will be the same but they are not.

I expected the fourth output to be `o Hello World!`.

Why is it?

How does the `*` effect in this case comparing to the first and second example?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

myString="Hello Hello World!"
ll="ll"
Hel="Hel"

echo "${myString#*$Hel}"     # lo Hello World!
echo "${myString#$Hel}"      # lo Hello World!
echo
echo "${myString#*$ll}" # o Hello World!
echo "${myString#$ll}"  # Hello Hello World!
```

Outputs:

```
lo Hello World!
lo Hello World!

o Hello World!
Hello Hello World!
```

Comment: Try "${myString##*$ll}"

Comment: What part of the *front end* you didn't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${myString#$ll}`, equivalent to `${myString#ll}`, removes `ll` at the **beginning** of `myString`, but `myString` does not begin in `ll` so it has no effect.

On the other hand, `${myString#*$ll}` allows the globbing character `*` to match `He` and `$ll` will (obviously) match `ll`.